# Is it possible to create custom visibility names like "public" and "private" in PHP?

Tags: php, class

Is it possible to define custom names for methods like

```
thing function foo() {
    //
}
```

Where `thing` is the custom name?

I want to have my own keywords like "public", "private", "static", and then get all `thing`s from a object, similar to how `get_class_methods()` gets methods.

Comment: @Ella Please expand on what actual problem you're trying to solve with this. There's probably a way to do it, just not this one.

Comment: Well, I have a set of classes, which act like "plugins" of the main application. And these plugins can "attach" a method to a URL path (when you go to that URL that function will run). I call these methods "events" and I wanted to know if it's possible to name them like `event function ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, PHP is not that extensible.

The closest thing you can do is use the __call method and implement some kind of restrictive behavior there. Be warned that this usually doesn't result in the most readable code so it should be done with care and good reason.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, you just need to change the PHP interpreter source code!

If you mean using PHP itself, well, no. Why would you wanna do that anyway?

Comment: It's just that I have some objects that must have certain methods, which I'd like to group them differently

Comment: Ella if you mean having a an actual grouping that is enforced by the interpreter, you may wanna take a look at Interfaces http://php.net/interface - As for the Visual Aid, you can either try to use a namespace, a comment (/* INDENTIFIER */ ...) or an naming convention.

Comment: Downvote for saying "Why would you wanna do that anyway?". Asking this question this way is inherently bad for innovation.

Answer (score 1):

In short: no it's not possible.

`public`, `protected`, `private` and `static` are keywords with specific meanings that change specific functionality. PHP does not support other meaning-free keywords.